# Bash arrays: compound assignments fail

Tags: arrays, bash

I have no idea why the compound array initialization does not work for me.

minimal example:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
MINRADIUS=( 'foo' 'bar' 'foobar' )
for i in {0..2..1}; do echo ${MINRADIUS[$i]}; done
```

output is

```
$ sh test.sh
(foo bar foobar)
```

with 2 additional blank lines.

Fieldwise initialization works:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
MINRADIUS[0]="foo"
MINRADIUS[1]="bar"
MINRADIUS[2]="foobar"
for i in {0..2..1}; do echo ${MINRADIUS[$i]}; done

$ sh test.sh
foo
bar
foobar
```

I have tried every possible combination of braces, quotes and "declare -a".

Could it be related to my bash version? I'm running version 4.1.2(1).

Comment: Can't reproduce on bash 4.3.11. Both cases output `foo
bar
foobar
` on separate lines.

Comment: What's the output of `MINRADIUS=( 'foo' 'bar' 'foobar' ); printf '(%s)\n' "${MINRADIUS[@]}"`?

Comment: Can you try `chmod +x test.sh` and then `./test.sh`? Or `bash test.sh`? Because `sh` can point to something different than bash.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you are not using bash. Shebang doesn't matter if you run your script throught `sh`. Try `bash` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below code and its working fine for me. Using bash 3.2.39(1)-release

```
#!/bin/bash
#
MINRADIUS=( 'foo' 'bar' 'foobar' )
for i in {0,1,2}; do echo ${MINRADIUS[$i]}; done
```

Output for this was

```
foo
bar
foobar
```

For me with your code it was giving an error

```
line 4: {0..1..2}: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "{0..1..2}")
```

Comment: still giving me  (foo bar foobar)  :(

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect there is some quoting going on in your first example using compound assignments.  Using this modified test script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "SHELL=${SHELL}"

echo 'Single-quoted v:'
v='(a b c)'; for i in {0..2}; do echo "v[$i]=${v[i]}"; done

echo 'Double-quoted v:'
v="(a b c)"; for i in {0..2}; do echo "v[$i]=${v[i]}"; done

echo 'Unquoted v:'
v=(a b c); for i in {0..2}; do echo "v[$i]=${v[i]}"; done
```

I get the following output:

```
$ sh test.sh
SHELL=/bin/bash
Single-quoted v:
v[0]=(a b c)
v[1]=
v[2]=
Double-quoted v:
v[0]=(a b c)
v[1]=
v[2]=
Unquoted v:
v[0]=a
v[1]=b
v[2]=c
```

If you quote the assignment, it becomes a simple variable assignment; a simple mistake to make that is easily overlooked.